How to use Google Cloud Run container variables in React client web app
I am developing a web app using React and the api in Golang. In development everything works fine, I use the vite server and the .env variables are loaded correctly.
Once deployed the react app is already built, so it already has its env variables budled. Furthermore, the cloud run variables are exposed only at the server, so they cannot accessed by the react app.
I was wondering if there is a way to inject GCP serects into the build process when the container is built through the trigger substitutions. I've already tried, but I get an error like
Your build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument: invalid value for 'build.substitutions': key in the template "MY_KEY" is not a valid built-in substitution.

Is it possible? Or is there a better way?
EDIT1:
I have been able to edit the trigger:
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '-t'
      - >-
        $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - '--build-arg'
      - MY_KEY=${_MY_KEY}
      - .
      - '-f'
      - Dockerfile
    id: Build
    secretEnv:
      - _MY_KEY
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - >-
        $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
    id: Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--platform=managed'
      - >-
        --image=$_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
images:
  - >-
    $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
substitutions:
  _all_the_standard_substitutions(hidden)
tags:
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run-managed
  - configurator-staging
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: >-
        projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/MY_SECRET/versions/latest
      env: _MY_KEY

In the Dockerfile I added followings:
ARG MY_KEY
ENV MY_KEY_FOR_APP=$MY_KEY

Once deployed the var is present, but it is an empty string.

Substitutions must start by _.  But share your Cloud Build config if you want more advice

Added some information.

Ahhhhh, so no, my previous comment is wrong. Let me post an answer.

When you call local env var in your step, you must use the double $$ to call this variable. Else, Cloud Build interpretes it as a substitution variable
In addition, you can get the value only in a script step and not a built-it step.
Look at my update: you must set an entry point, and call the docker build command as you do it in your usual bash environment
Try this
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        docker build --no-cache -t $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA --build-arg MY_KEY=$${_MY_KEY} . -f Dockerfile
    id: Build
    secretEnv:
      - _MY_KEY

And so, no need to start it with _ the secret env.

Thanks, but nope, once triggered, the argument is build --no-cache -t europe-west7-docker.pkg.dev/fleet7426211-r5/cloud-run-source-deploy/fgfdgfdgfd/dfgdfg-staging:ecfbf2d194285cdfgdfgdf4eb8061f7804 --build-arg MY_KEY=${_MY_KEY} . -f Dockerfile It echoes ${_MY_KEY} instead the right value.

In the docs I read $$_FOO evaluates to the literal string $_FOO.

My bad, I forgot a major trap!!! see my update!!!

Nope, the argument still does not show the real value, but MY_KEY=${_MY_KEY}

Do you use the entrypoint and the -c in the args?

Yes, I copy pasted your snippet.

Is it possible that the retrieved secret is an empty string due to permission problems?

Normally not, if Cloud Build do not have access to secret, it should fail.

Unfortunately it is not working for me. I decided to hardcode the var into the trigger instead of loading it from the secret manager.
